# How do I use the setting "Park (Day)" for the environment under Lighting from the gltf viewer to A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, gltf

I'm trying to load a gltf model ([link](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/golden-snitch-sgp29-ddf3f777809845df8c388cd346067d15)) to A-frame, but it appears dark, I've checked it using the [link](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) and the difference is that in the gltf viewer, under lighting, there's a field called environment which is set to "Park (Day)".

with environment set to: None

[image]

with environment set to: Park (Day)
[image]

How do I apply this setting to my model in A-Frame?

The other difference is the gammeOutput property which I have already fixed with "colorManagement: true" in the a-scene renderer.

Currently using version 0.9.0 of A-Frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see an image being reflected by the model, it's an [environment map](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#environment-maps). Its used when you want your object to reflect its surroundings or any other environment.

You can set it on primitives with either `envMap` (cubemap) or `sphericalEnvMap` (360 image) property:

```
<a-sphere material="roughness:0; sphericalEnvMap: #myImage>
```

Check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/g3kx59p8/12/) fiddle.

---

With models, you'd need to dig in a bit deeper. You'd need to `traverse` the model, and set each mesh `envMap` property:

```
let texture = THREE.TextureLoader()
const mesh = element.getObject3D('mesh');
const envMap = texture;
if (!mesh) return;

mesh.traverse(function (node) {
  if (node.material && 'envMap' in node.material) {
    node.material.envMap = envMap;
    node.material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I understand what it is now. I will try and apply my own environment map then.

Comment: @AxelRaymundo i see its working, glad i could help :)